# Stopping a bot command in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I have written a bot which spams like this :

```
@bot.command()
async def start (ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send("Pls use correct channels for discussion")
        await asyncio.sleep(300)
```

When i enter $start, the function starts. How to make a new command like $stop to stop the spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Cohen only prevents you from starting it, but it doesn't allow you to stop the infinite loop once it's going. What you should *actually* do, is check the value of the variable **inside of** the loop, in order to be able to stop it. Also, use `booleans` instead of hardcoding "true" and "false" in `strings`.

```py
spam = True

@bot.command()
async def start (ctx):
    # EDIT: Set spam to True again so you can restart the loop
    global spam
    spam = True

    while true:
        # If "spam" is set to False, stop looping
        if not spam:
            break

        await ctx.send("Pls use correct channels for discussion")
        await asyncio.sleep(300)


@bot.command()
async def stop (ctx):
    global spam
    spam = False
    await ctx.send('spam stopped')
```

This checks whether or not it should keep running on every iteration of the loop. That way, when you set it to `False`, the loop stops.

Comment: this code does not work if i start it again

Comment: @Trojan Don't forget to set ``spam`` to ``True`` again, otherwise it'll never run again... You could, for example, do that at the top of the ``Start`` command, where you always want it to run (otherwise you wouldn't call ``Start``). I've added that line in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way of doing this is just to set a variable if the spam has started and when it is stopped. When you run the start command, the spam variable is already true and would run because the if statement continues with the while loop. When running the stop command, it simply just sets the spam variable to false and wouldn’t keep running the spam

```
spam = True

@bot.command()
async def start (ctx):
    if spam:
        while True:
            await ctx.send("Pls use correct channels for discussion")
            await asyncio.sleep(300)


@bot.command()
async def stop (ctx):
    global spam
    spam = False
    await ctx.send('spam stopped')
```